# Why cannot xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu be backed up?

Tags: deja-dup

I am using deja dup for backups. Since a few weeks it keeps on complaining

```
Could not backup the following files< Please make sure you are able to open them.
/home/username/.config/menus/applications-merged/xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu
```

I do not recall having changed anything to that file. It's permissions are `-rw-------` (like all other files in that directory).

Any idea how to fix this problem? Should I just delete the file?

Answer (score 0):

That file is empty and is a **dummy**, so, when is empty is not used, when is not empty DejaDup don't ignore him.

It doesn't say error... at most is an INFO message, in my system the file is empty and was recreated whenever I moved it. This kind of message can be safely ignored.

Comment: But why would DejaDup give an error message for an empty file?

Comment: It doesn't say error... at most is an INFO message, in my system the file is empty and was recreated whenever I moved it.